# Why do we need to specify parenthesis while passing the function to a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am new to Angular and trying out the directives. Following is the code

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="scopetest" ng-controller="controller">
  <div phone action="callhome()"> </div>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
angular.module("scopetest", [])
.controller("controller", function($scope){
  $scope.callhome = function(){
    alert("called");
  }
})
.directive("phone", function(){
  return {
    scope: {
      action:"&"
    },
    template: "<button ng-click='action()' >Call</button>"
  };
});
```

My question is if we are passing the `callhome` function to the `action` attribute, and on `ng-click` we are calling the `action` function with parenthesis, then why do we need to specify the parenthesis while setting the attribute on phone directive `ng-click='action()'`? Why doesn't just `ng-click='action'` work? We are already specifying `action="callhome()"`. Why needed at both places?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [the attribute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) doesn't specify a function. It specifies [an *expression*](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression). Most of the time you want that expression to be a function call (and function calls need `()` (or `apply` or `new` or etc).

You could specify something else instead:

```
ng-click="window.myGlobal = true;"
```

Comment: thanks. Does this means that this also applies to my directive `action="callhome()"`. why not `action="callhome"` ?